# Does query plan get recomputed if we close and reopen a prepared statement?

Tags: java, database, prepared-statement, sql-execution-plan

Need some insight on how this works

I have the following piece of code

```
  public static void updateOrdersPrepared(int productId , String productName){

    Connection con = getConnection();

    try {
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement 
                  ("update Orders set productname = ? where Prod_Id  = ?");

            pstmt.setInt(2, productId);
            pstmt.setString(1, productName);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            pstmt.close();
            con.close();

    } catch(SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Updated into Orders Table");
}
```

Now if this method is called 'N' number of times , will the query plan for the prepared statement be computed 'N' times or just once ?

Is there a real advantage of using prepared statements in such scenarios ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on the RDBMS you are targeting.

SQL Server is able to cache a parameterised query plan for the statement `"update Orders set productname = ? where Prod_Id  = ?"` so there will be a benefit. However, it is such a simple query that the benefit will likely be quite small.

You should measure in your particular circumstances (is your server CPU bound, or I/O bound? It's usually the latter).

As you are aware. the real advantage to using a PreparedStatement is preparing it once and then calling many times with different parameters set.

Comment: Will there be any difference if I use a normal statement instead of a prepared statement in this particular scenario ?